# How to style pandas dataframe using two keys dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
NUM = list(range(1, 29))

R1 = np.random.randint(-10, 11, size=28)
R2 = np.random.randint(-10, 11, size=28)
R3 = np.random.randint(-10, 11, size=28)
R4 = np.random.randint(-10, 11, size=28)
R5 = np.random.randint(-10, 11, size=28)

data = {
    'NUM': NUM,
    'R1': R1,
    'R2': R2,
    'R3': R3,
    'R4': R4,
    'R5': R5
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to style it using the following dictionary:

```
import random

claves = [(f'R{i}', j) for i in range(1, 6) for j in range(1, 29)]

colores_posibles = ['yellow', None, 'orange', 'red', 'purple']

color_dict = {clave: random.choice(colores_posibles) for clave in claves}
```

As you can see, the color of the style depends on the values of the   **R's** and **NUM** columns (NUM column take values between 1 and 28), which are the keys of the dictionary.

With some effort I have arrived at the following code to apply the style:

```
def apply_style(val):
    if isinstance(val, pd.Series):
        col_name = val.name
        pos_num_key = (col_name, val['NUM'])
        if pos_num_key in color_dict:
            color = color_dict[pos_num_key]  
            return 'background-color: {}'.format(color)  
    return ''

styled_df = df.style.applymap(apply_style, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, 'R1':'R5'])
```

But this is not working, I can't find the error, or maybe there is another simpler approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`applymap` applies the function to each cell, so `isinstance` will alway fail. Use `apply, which operates on the columns, and return an array with the same length of the column:

```
def apply_style(series):
    out = []
    for idx in series.index:
        color = color_dict.get((series.name, df.loc[idx,'NUM']))
        out.append(f'background-color: {color}' if color else color)
    return out

styled_df = df.style.apply(apply_style, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, 'R1':'R5'])
```

You would get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Make sense, but I am taking the followig error: ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rstrip'```

Comment: That works fine on my system. You can try replace `else color` with `else ''`.

Comment: That did the magic, thanks!